# how cann I show console.log() with gulp

Tags: gulp, electron

I'm using gulp to develope a electron app.

in my gulpfile.js I defined

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src( src + '/js/render.js' )
    .pipe(browserify({
      transform: 'reactify',
      extensions: 'browserify-css',
      debug: true
    }))
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.error('Error!', err.message);
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(app + '/js'));
});
```

ok, I see all my errors, but how can I see the 'normale' console.log outputs?

Comment: Where have you tried to do console.log?

Comment: yes. when starting direct with electron . I can see all outputs

Comment: the console.log is in the main.js or in der the render.js files

Comment: `console.log` should always work either in gulpfile.js, or in electron main or render processes. For an Electron renderer process you will need to check within the Web Inspector to see the output.